# Computer wont even go into bios after installing new hdd

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I have in my pc 3 hdd 2 ssd's, windows is on one of the two ssd's. i wanted to get rid of the old hdd's and put all the stuff on one drive, so I had gotten a 6tb wd red nas pro hdd (WD6003FFBX). i did not unplug my pc from the wall, i didnt feel the need to. I shut my pc down properly, I put it in my computer disconnecting the c: ssd drive by accident. I turned the pc on and the bios came up. i realized that i picked the wrong drive. I held the power button to shut the pc off. I swapped the drive cables, unplugged the other ssd that didnt have windows on it,and put the red nas in its place. When i turn my pc on it lights up, and the graphics card fans take turns doing half a spin every few seconds. The watercooling radiator fans are on slowly turning. After about 1 minute of this my keyboard and mouse light up but still no bios. I can hear the hdd's whirring but other than that nothing happens now. If i unplug all of the drives the same thing happens. I even took graphics card and used mobo vga and also took out cmos battery to reset mobo to no avail what should i replace or do? Thank you.

- Power supply is 650w corsair
- Motherboard is msi Z370 GAMING PLUS
- Ram is Corsair Value Select Series 1 stick of 16GB DDR4 2133MHzPC4-17000 CL15 DIMM
- Intel BX80684I78086K i7-8086K Limited Edition Processor
- Evga nvidia 1080ti graphics card
- corsair Hydro Series™ H100i v2 Extreme Performance Liquid CPU Cooler
- 2 medium sized chassis fans

Answer (score 1):

Please check again for any disconnected components, then reseat your RAM module.
Unclip it, grasp it by the edges with *clean and statically discharged hands*, remove, replace, and reclip. Then reassemble the rest of the PC and turn it back on.

The first thing BIOS does in any form of Power-On-Self-Test is quantify available RAM, typically followed by disk enumeration.
Your symptoms exactly match a failure to verify any RAM at all, which is likely as you only have a single module.

It can become unseated by any sudden movement, such as a nearby stomp or jolt during case separation.

There's also a chance the RAM may have been inadvertently damaged, although this is less likely.

Comment: I reseated the ram but it did not help i even found another stick of ddr4 and put it in alone in a different slot and it didnt work either im going to try a new power supply but i dont think that will help either. Do you think it could be the motherboard?